# Answers for the question word "what kind of"

Tags: exam-questions

> Given:
>
> The  Philippines  is  a  predominantly  Catholic  nation  and  no  country  in  ASEAN  can  rival  its centuries-old  churches,  with  their  antique  religious  objects.  Fascinating  churches,  to  be  found  around Metro  Manila  are:  the  Malate  Church  with  its  images  of  Our  Lady  of  Remedies;  the  Las  Pinas Church,  with  its  165-year-old  organ  made  entirely  of  bamboo;  and  San  Sebastian  Church  built  in 1981, the only  Gothic  steel  church in  the  country.
>
> Question:
>
> What kind of church is San Sebastian Church?
>
> Possible Answers:
>
> 1.San Sebastian Church is a Gothic steel church.
>
> 2.San Sebastian Church is the only Gothic steel church in the country.

I can't decide which answer is suitable for the question
"What kind of--". I like both as they can describe the types of Church.

Comment: The question is asking about the design and construction of the church, not its location or uniqueness, so the fact that it is the only church in the country is irrelevant to the question. Therefore, the first answer is the appropriate one.

Comment: The question is about the curch attribute & properties(like Mick said the design and construction).

Comment: But note that "what kind of" doesn't only mean "What is it made out of"... without the prompt it can mean any sort of descriptor. "It's a country church" (as opposed to a city church) "It's a Protestant church"... etc. The only reason this question is referring to the design of the church is because that is all the information you are given. Note, "country" in that sentence means "nation", not "non-urban areas".

Comment: I provided more in the question.

Answer (score 2):

Since the word "country" refers to the Philippines, it doesn't describe the building and shouldn't be included into your answer. The correct answer is number 1, as Mick mentioned in his comment.

> San Sebastian Church is a **Gothic steel** church.

The word "country" describes a church in the following sentence.

> It was a quiet country church.("country " means "rural").

Answer (score 2):

Answer #1 answers the question given. Answer #2 would be more appropriate for a question such as:

> What is unique about San Sebastian Church?